# Any open areas to work in non equilibrium thermodynamics for a Phd student?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, soft-question, research-level

I see that many papers written on fundamentals of thermodynamics(theory) nowadays are by some old professors somewhere(there may be exceptions). Most active young faculty don't seem to be seriously interested in reinterpreting thermodynamics like nonequlibrium thermodynamics i.e. continuing the work of Ilya Prigogine etc. So is this worth while for a graduate student starting his research career to work in this area? Any open problems a fresh graduate student can aim to solve theoretically?

Comment: Not quite sure if that's what you're looking for (that's why it's a comment), but you might also be interested in non-equilibrium statistical mechanics, which has applications in biology, physics, computer simulation, computational statistics,... I can think of a few interesting theoretical questions, most of them related to my work. You might be interested in [Crook's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crooks_fluctuation_theorem), the [Jarzynski equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarzynski_equality) and in the work of John Chodera (I'm heavily biased towards simulation-related stuff).

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in the foundations of thermodynamics on the quantum level then there is plenty of work being done, including by young 'uns. Actually it's pretty fashionable, in the UK quantum physics community at least. If you like the sound of this then you could look up, for example, the work of Sandu Popescu, Jonathan Oppenheim, David Jennings, Janet Anders, Vlatko Vedral, Robert Spekkens and co-workers. Obviously that list of names is heavily biased by my own limited knowledge and preference.